# How to write data from db to state at boot?

Tags: reactjs

What if I want to load data from my database into my state immediately when the page loads? To display them when the page loads

Now I'm trying to get the total profit from the database in state using **useEffect**, but for some reason the data is not loading

```js
 // my state
 const [income, setIncome] = useState([]);
  
 useEffect(() => {
   onTest();
 }, []);

 // get data my bd (invoiceList)
 const onTest = () => {
   return invoiceList.map(i => {
     setIncome([i.amount]);
   })
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Perhaps there are other ways to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what `invoiceList` is? I don't see a backend request, and without one, there's no way to access a DB from the front end. Also, it's sort of weird to call `setIncome` repeatedly--it'll only contain the last item. `setIncome(invoiceList)` would be a more sane use case, I'd think, assuming `invoiceList` is an array.

Comment: This is my list from the database, get it with redux

Comment: OK, then why not pass it as a prop? You only need `useEffect` if you're making a request or something async. Seems like you already have everything in memory, so the problem reduces to "how do I pass an array as a prop to a component and display it?", if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Apparently, yes ...

Comment: So just `const MyComponent = ({invoiceList}) => <ul>invoiceList.map(e => <li>{JSON.stringify(e)}</li>)}</ul>;`?

Comment: Where to call MyComponent? Data must be displayed at boot time

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "data must be displayed at boot time". When a component is created, if it's a class, its `render` func is called and if it's a FC, it returns the jsx which gets rendered. Just put the data into the jsx and return it and React will render it "at boot time". Create it with `<MyComponent invoiceList={yourInvoiceList} />`. Your example is incomplete as it doesn't show the function or its return value, so it's impossible to tell what the problem could be. `invoiceList` is also not shown, so there's no way to know what it is.

Comment: The idea is that when the page is loaded, I will show the income on my graph, and the income data is in the "invoiceList", the data from which I want to transfer to state to give their graph
https://i.imgur.com/1Hn5uaQ.png?1

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `invoiceList` as dependency in useEffect to watch if `invoiceList` receives data before running `onTest()`.

```
    useEffect(() => {
     if (invoiceList) { 
       onTest()
     };
    }, [invoiceList]);
```